how to get rid of indentation pipe character
I'm using nvim with lazyvim (i guess) setup and all the good stuff. (language server, treesitter, packer). It's great and all, but one thing is driving me crazy:
Independent of the used language, nvim marks indentations with the pipe (|) symbol, so code becomes:
def fu():
|   print( "fu" )
|   if True:
|   |   print( "yes" )
...

and so on. These symbols get copied when I mark them in the terminal and are very annoying.
How can I get rid of those pipe symbols?
Edit:
removing ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/indent-blankline.nvim worked!

Those indentation highlights are provided by two built-in plugins:

echasnovski/mini.indentscope
lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim

You can disable them, by creating lua/plugins/disabled.lua file in your neovim configuration folder with the following content:
return {
  { "echasnovski/mini.indentscope", enabled = false },
  { "lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim", enabled = false },
}

List of built-in plugins for lazyvim distribution

Hi. Thanks. Where does "lua" directory live? I have a .config/nvim/plugins. But when I put the script there it gets loaded (as shown by :scriptnames) but does not disable the pipes.

On a default setup (that they provide to try via docker), it looks like this: .config/nvim/lua/ so you have to create this file like this: .config/nvim/lua/plugins/disabled.lua

I think that you can look for a file called example.lua and put disabled.lua next to it

It got loaded in plugin/disabled.lua but not in lua/plugins/disabled.lua. (I have no example.lua). But it didn't work anyway :(

What worked now is: I removed ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/indent-blankline.nvim.
For the first time in X month I can finally copy paste again. Thanks a lot!!
